# Remove the Argument from a views URL

Tags: views, hooks

I have a view with an exposed filter using the hierarchical select module for taxonomy.

`/browse?category=12345`

On the same view, I have an argument which does the same thing.

`/browse/12345`

I want my users to navigate using only the select filter, but this doesn't support breadcrumbs and page titles like the argument does. I wrote a bit of code to inject the filter value into the argument, and that works fine, but the next time I change a filter and refresh the view, the URL changes to that previous value while showing the new value.

`/browse/(term id of last selection)?category=(term id of new selection)`
aka
`/browse/111?category=333`

How can I discard this url change and keep things how they work the first time?

```
function MODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  switch ($view->name) {
    case 'resources':
      if ($display_id == 'page_1') {
        if ($_GET['category']) {
          $args = array($_GET['category']);
        }
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is a caching issue, disable temporally the caching for views, and see what happen? t disable the caching for views visit this page "/admin/structure/views/settings/advanced"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exposed filter form is always going to add a query string to the current URL as it's a simple GET form.

You need a form with a submit handler that redirects to the argument based path. You could do this to the existing exposed filter with `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` or create a custom form and expose it in a block.

To make the existing form redirect you'd need to do something like:

```
function mytheme_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#method'] = 'POST';
  $form['#submit'] = array('mytheme_redirect_taxonomy');
}

function mytheme_redirect_taxonomy($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = '/browse/' . $form_state['values']['category'];
}
```

Comment: I understand what your saying. My taxonomy select requires the use of the query string value, unless I were to somehow get that to look at the argument as well.

Comment: I think I need to implement your code sample so that the exposed form posts to the view argument. Then when the filter loads also pass that the value from the argument too. This way I would eliminate the query string requirement completely.

Comment: I cannot get this to work. `$form_state['redirect']` in a submit handler does not redirect my form, at all. I was wondering if it was the  hierarchical select so I created a new view with an exposed node_type filter and still nothing.